# (Redmine) How to add Custom fields for Notes

Tags: redmine

I'd like to add some Custom fields to Notes which Issues belong to.

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEB9j.png)

I've read the guide below:
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineCustomFields

On that page, I can see Fields for Issues, Fields for Spent time entries and Fields for Activities. But It seems that there is no information I'm looking for.

Are there any settings or plugins?

I'm using 2.6.6.stable for now. But I'll update Redmine to latest version if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Maxim Krušina, I’ve come around to seek your advice again. I'd found your post #6971 on Redmine forum [http://www.redmine.org/issues/6971]. I agree with your idea and I don't know why nobody has developed, those of functions on not only Redmine, but also any plugins even now. Are there some reasons or hurdles to develop such of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunatelly, there is no custom field for issue updates (notes), only for tickets itself.

Anyway, I strongly recommand to upgrade to the latest production version.

Regards
Maxim

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand. I' ll find another way somehow. thanks again.